# Shortcode leaves no space for other elements?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, shortcode

I've created my own shortcode. I'm unable to share the code unfortunately ;/

When I use it on my pages it behaves strange. It always has the highest priority. I mean something like that in page editor:

```
Text
[shortcode]
```

Outputs on the page:

```
< shortcode contents > 
Text
```

And this in page editor:

```
[shortcode]
Text
[shortcode]
```

Gives:

```
< shortcode contents >
< shortcode contents >
Text
```

So I'm unable to put anything before and between my shortcodes.

To say more, my shortcodes use a few ifs, foreachs and a loop (they're grabbing and displaying data from custom post type).

Any ideas why it happnes?

[edit]

**OK, so I've been using echoes instead of return. My bad.
Is there any way of return my whole function without editing every single line and adding $output etc.?**

Comment: very hard to tell without looking at the code but maybe you have a content filter other then your shortcode, try adding remove_all_filters("the_content",2);

Comment: Check to make sure that your shortcodes are returning their content, rather than echoing. An "echo" in a shortcode will always appear at the very top of your content, because the shortcodes are processed before the content is output.

Comment: @goldenapple Oops, only read your comment after posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that your shortcode echos it's output rather than returning it.

So in your shortcode function, remove any direct output (that is stuff between `?>.....<?php` and any `echo`s and rather gather your output in a variable  and return that:

```
function my_shortcode_cb($atts) {
    ....
    $output = ....
    $output .= ....
    return $output;
}
```

**More detail:**

So instead of

```
while ($a != $b) {
    echo "<ul>";
    if ($c == $d) {
        foreach ($e as $k => $v) {
            ?>
            <li class="item-<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

you do:

```
$output = '';
while ($a != $b) {
    $output .= "<ul>"
    if ($c == $d) {
        foreach ($e as $k => $v) {
            $output .= "<li class=\"item-".$k."\">".$v."</li>";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
}
return $output;
```

Or, if you wanna be cheap ;-), you can do this:

```
ob_start();
while ($a != $b) {
    echo "<ul>";
    if ($c == $d) {
        foreach ($e as $k => $v) {
            ?>
            <li class="item-<?php echo $k; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
return ob_get_clean();
```

BTW: If your shortcode callback is really really long, then chances are that it's got lots of potential for refactoring. And if you'd do that, chances are that you'd assemble your output from strings returned by function calls, anyways.

Comment: @wyrfel, oh my God. You may be right BUT this is going to make serious mess in my code. My shortcode is very very long, full of loops and if statements... Is returning it all as one variable/set of variables the only way? :( Not intuitive at all.

Comment: @Wordpressor: You can keep all your code with all the supersecret loops and eventualities as is, just whereever you use an echo or escape back out of php mode and into html mode, append it to your output variable instead. It's really not that much difference.

Comment: @Wordpressor: see edits.

Comment: @wyrfel return ob_get_clean(); outputs [myshortcode] instead of it contents ;/ I'm unable to fit EVERY single echo line in $output. It'd take around 10 years and will destroy whitespace completely, in addition as I said before there are tons of nested and complicated statements and loops. HOLY COW :/

Comment: The [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) gives clear examples of returning data(no echoes in those examples). Did you not check the documentation before you wrote the numerous shortcode functions you have?

Comment: @t31os, this is madness. My shortcode generates almost the whole page, I have sometimes around 10 if statements per line (and each one also returs data using echo), not even counting php functions like bloginfos etc. Packing it all together into one variable will destroy all the whitespace as well as code's usability (changing anything after that change will be a nightmare). BTW I didn't write it.

Comment: Your code is not usable already. You won’t lose anything. And no, there is no way around.

Comment: You code doesn't conform to how shortcodes are intended to operate, what would you have me suggest? (if you're not rewriting the functions, then output buffering is pretty much the only option).

Comment: @t31os, @toscho, there in addition to buffering there is also Heredoc, I'm gonna check them both. I know "my" shortcode is ~wrong at this moment, but to be honest adding $output everywhere will destroy almost every code completely in my opinion. Yes, it will work, but changing anything is going to be much much much harder.

Comment: @Wordpressor: Using a variable doesn't destroy any whitespace. You can still insert whitespace however much you like both in your code and in the output. Also, if your shortcode generates the whole page (almost) there is something inherently wrong with it. The template should generate the page, a shortcode should do a tiny little thing to the content...one of these things each ('do one thing, do it right'). You really make this shortcode sound worse and worse with every comment. I'd say abandon it and start from scratch.

Comment: @Wordpressor: And...code that buffers output in a variable before dumping it on screen is usually more maintainable, as you can refactor it more easily, redirect parts of your output between functions, run regexp-commands over it, include it within other output etc. etc. .